# What columns stores the slug in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress, what column stores the slug (either auto generated, or user entered)?

I can not find this in either `wp_posts` or `wp_postmeta`. The `wp_posts` `GUID` stores a direct link, but not the slug.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The slug for Posts and Pages are stored in the `wp_posts` posts table in the column `post_name`. Just be aware that all the automatic saves as well as attachments are stored in the same table, so there will not be a solid column full of slugs, but only one for each "parent" (parent to the revisions) Post or Page.

Comment: Also be aware that slugs are regenerated each time the post title or slug is modified.

Comment: @Damienwilson Not in case of title. Modifying post/page title won't effect slug anymore in current version of wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of heresy, I am going to say it is not completely true. I was updating some slugs and found the post_name field does not change.
On further searching, I found the wp_postmeta table has an entry under meta_key name 'custom_permalink' that has the latest slug path.

Comment: At least in the latest version (5.2.3) the `post_name` column is changed on every slug change.