# Where does wordpress store redirects?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

For example.

1. I create new page with permalink /test1
2. then after publishing I change the permalink to /test2
3. then if I browse to /test1 I get redirected to /test2

It looks like somewhere wordpress has stored a redirect from test1 to test2. However I can't find it anywhere.

Can someone please help me figuring out what is going on?

Thanks.

I'm using the Avada theme by themefusion. The only redirect plugin installed is simple 301 redirects. This plugin doesn't store redirects automatically and I do not believe that this plugin creates a problem. As the "problem" also occurs on other wordpress websites which do not have simple 301 redirects installed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077733/what-columns-stores-the-slug-in-wordpress

Answer (score -2):

Wordpress does that by default. If you want to remove that functionality try with adding `remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');` to your theme's (preferably child theme's) functions.php file.